# Converting a UNIX Timestamp to Formatted Date String

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Using PHP, I want to convert UNIX timestamps to date strings similar to this: `2008-07-17T09:24:17Z`

How do I convert a timestamp such as `1333699439` to `2008-07-17T09:24:17Z`?

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Try [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) like this:

```
<?php
$timestamp=1333699439;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
?>
```

Comment: Please not that `gmdate()` returns the date/time in GMT. `date()` will return the local date/time.

Comment: Above comment doesn't make sense in this context. Using date with the second parameter as timestamp, as shown in answer, will not print the date in local timezone. Date will be printed with timezone info ignored, cause the timestamp doesn't have timezone info. gmdate and date with second timestamp parameter as 1333699439 will print the same date time.

Comment: @MattK: Which makes sense, since Z indicate UTC.

Tinus: Unix timestamps do not contain timezone offsets. `date` and `gmdate`'s output will differ based on the TZ variable (on *nix at least)

Comment: You can check this http://www.phpzag.com/convert-unix-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-in-php/

Comment: It would also be nice if this answer included the solution for the opposite problem, converting a formatted date to UNIX time.

Comment: `$date = new DateTime('2018-01-01 00:00:00'); $date->format('U');`

Comment: PHP v5.6 generates from timestamp 1540426286647 -> 50784-03-01 but should be 2018-10-25. When using gmdate('Y-m-d', $lastmodifieddate_ts);

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi You would have to divide the timestamp by 1000 to get proper year, as this timestamp is stored in milliseconds.

Answer (score 145):

use date function  `date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`

Use `date('c',time())` as format to convert to ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5) - `2012-04-06T12:45:47+05:30`

use `date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",1333699439)` to get `2012-04-06T13:33:59Z`

Here are some of the formats date function supports

```
<?php
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
?>
```

Comment: how can i convert specific timestamp with 'c'? for example 1333699439

Comment: this doesnt work date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",1333699439) i got 2012-04-06EDT04:03:59-14400

Comment: @Ahmet - Note use of double and single quotes when defining the string

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Just a questions: date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",1333699439) to get 2012-04-06T13:33:59Z --- What is that T and Z? I guess T is for time and Z for? Thank you again.

Comment: @user2060451 anything preceded by a backslash is shown as the literal character in the resulting time string

Comment: @user2060451: Z is supposed to indicate UTC time (in which case gmdate should be used...) Check out ISO8601 info on your favourite research resource.

Answer (score 74):

Assuming you are using PHP5.3 then the modern way of handling dates is via the native [DateTime class](http://uk.php.net/datetime). To get the current time you can just call

```
$currentTime = new DateTime();
```

To create a DateTime object from a specific timestamp (i.e. not now)

```
$currentTime = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'U', $timestamp );
```

To get a formatted string you can then call

```
$formattedString = $currentTime->format( 'c' );
```

See the [manual page here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: how can i convert specific timestamp with this? for example 1333699439

Comment: @Norse Of course I read his post. All the info he needed was in my post. All he had to do was read the PHP docs for the DateTime object. I've edited my post to make it even clearer. The DateTime object is the way to go in PHP and all newbies should be encouraged to use it. As yet, I'm the only one who's provided that answer. Btw I find your comment a bit aggressive and not quite in the spirit of SO.

Comment: @Ahmetvardar See my edit although all this is in the PHP docs to which I provided a link. I strongly urge you to start using the DateTime object. It provides excellent support for dates/times including timezones etc

Answer (score 27):

It is very important to set a default timezone to get the correct result

```
<?php
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

// timestamp
$timestamp = 1307595105;

// output
echo date('d M Y H:i:s Z',$timestamp);
echo date('c',$timestamp);
?>
```

Online conversion help: http://freeonlinetools24.com/timestamp

Comment: In ISO8601, `Z` is used to indicate that it is a UTC time, so the timezone should be set to `UTC`

Answer (score 25):

```
<?php
$timestamp=1486830234542;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp/1000);
?>
```

Comment: Works without the divide part. Otherwise the date defaults to 1970.

Comment: This works on me. Idk why others says it doesn't work. Prob because I'm using PHP7.2?

Comment: @LapiztheProgrammer yeah its depend on PHP versions

Comment: I'm getting the value from the external API where it looks like: '1623923723000'. In this case, the dividing part is necessary to get the correct date: '2021-06-17 11:55:23'.
Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: The value must be in milliseconds.  date must be assuming a unix timestamp in seconds.

Comment: for me the result needs to add `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");` to work correct

Answer (score 9):

The DateTime class takes a string in the constructor. If you prefix the timestamp with a @-character you create a DateTime object with the timestamp. For formating use the 'c' format ... a predefined ISO 8601 compound format.

If could use the DateTime class like this ... set the right timezone or leave it out if you want a UTC time.

```
$dt = new DateTime('@1333699439');
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dt->format('c');
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php
- more examples and timezones https://time.einfach.jetzt/?t=1333699439

Answer (score 7):

```
$unixtime_to_date = date('jS F Y h:i:s A (T)', $unixtime);
```

This should work to.

Answer (score 6):

You can do like as.....

```
$originalDate = "1585876500";

echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", date($originalDate));
```

Answer (score 4):

most people doesn't read comment, and there is problem with `gmdate()` in accepted answer, it return time in GMT, so if we use `date_default_timezone_set(zone)` it will not work, instead use `date()`.

```
<?php

$ts = 1664706166;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
$gmdate = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
echo  "date()  : $date\n";
echo  "gmdate(): $gmdate\n\n";

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
$gmdate = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
echo  "date()  : $date\n";
echo  "gmdate(): $gmdate <- GMT\n";

/* result
date()  : 2022-10-02 10:22:46
gmdate(): 2022-10-02 10:22:46

After set timezone
date()  : 2022-10-02 17:22:46
gmdate(): 2022-10-02 10:22:46 <- GMT
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the information in this conversation so helpful that  I just wanted to add how I figured it out by using the timestamp from my MySQL database and a little PHP

```
 <?= date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\+01:00",strtotime($column['loggedin'])) ?>
```

The output was: 2017-03-03T08:22:36+01:00

Thanks very much Stewe you answer was a eureka for me.