# PHP, Converting timestamp to a date

Tags: php, epoch

From an external website I receive, amongst other data, a date/time stamp like this
`1346729259806` or `1346734102948`
I have been trying to see what the best way to convert this into a formatted date/time readable for later use.

I found out that the timestamp is Epoch format in miliseconds.
Is there a regular way to convert this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a UNIX Timestamp to Formatted Date String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string)

Answer (score 6):

`date()` function takes the second parameter as the timestamp.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1346729259806/1000);
```

Comment: i was sending from Android to php and it wasnt converting. Then i saw your "/1000" xD

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the timestamp to date in mysql by using `DATE` and `FROM_UNIXTIME` function. The command given bellow,

```
FROM_UNIXTIME
SELECT create FROM phpkit ;
```

The output created:

> 1216053466

Then:

```
SELECT DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `created` ) ) AS pDate FROM phpkit
```

Output:

> 2008-07-14

I found the source from the following [link](http://youropensource.com/projects/61-How-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-MYSQL).