# How to convert the extract time in "hr:min:sec" from UNIX time stamp in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm a newbie to this UNIX Timestamp concept. So got stuck with a little issue.
I want to extract the Time(in hr:min:sec format and attached with am/pm word) from UNIX Timestamp (e.g. 1335959743). 
Can you help me in achieving the desired time format along with the string am/pm attached to it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://php.net/DateInterval may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
date('h:i:s A', $timestamp);
```

The "h" is lowercase to show time in format AM/PM. If you want 12/24, use "H" (uppercase).

Comment: Thanks once again for your precious help. Your magic did the trick for me. I've marked your answer as right.

Answer (score 1):

The [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function is what you need:

```
$timestamp = time();//or whatever your timestamp source is
date('h:i:s A', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Been asked before [converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string)

```
echo date("H:i:s a",$timestamp);
```