# PHP timestamp -> strtotime -> timestamp

Tags: php

I am calling an external API and one of the parameters I have to pass is the date but in a string like (now or last week) this in turn gets converted to a timestamp using strtotime.

The problem is that I already have a timestamp but the API requires a string.

So my question is how do I take a timestamp and convert it to a string that strtotime() will return the exact same timestamp?

Thanks

Comment: looks like i need to convert the timestamp to something like "+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"

Comment: if that return mm-dd-YYY hour:minute:second. then is that be ok for You requirement?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string

Comment: @ripa: That's totally different. This question is asking "how do I take a timestamp and **convert it to a string that strtotime() will return the exact same timestamp?**" not "how do I convert a timestamp to a formatted date string". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) you are allowed to provide a unix timestamp, if you precede it with an @:

```
 Unix Timestamp   "@" "-"? [0-9]+   "@1215282385"
```

Comment: And how are you so sure that the OP is using DateTime class? He said he's using `strtotime()`.

Comment: @AmalMurali What are you  talking about? If you read the manual for `strtotime()` it clearly refers you to these "date and time formats" pages, as the formats it accepts. It even starts with **This section describes all the different formats that the strtotime(), DateTime and date_create() parser understands.**

Comment: @Nanne: Yes, I'm aware of that. However, I was confused myself after I first read the question and your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

you can convert using `date`

example

`date(DATE_ISO8601, $your_timestamp);`

`strtotime` will be able to parse the ISO8601 date back on the other side