# I just want to show time in a 24 hour clock in php when my form submits

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am using  below line of code

```
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

but in my database it shows like following format. (`unixtimestamp`)

```
1419957753
```

How i can change it?

Comment: Really?
Have you ever tried to search about date() function in PHP?

Comment: At least tell me what should i do

Comment: That's a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10040291/1883647) seems to be duplicated by this.

Comment: All of the things I'd like to say right now would have my comment removed, but suffice it to say that perhaps you should consult with the PHP documentation or perhaps there is a service with a name that rhymes with Schmoogle that will allow you to search the internet for useful resources.

Comment: Check the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and the rest of PHP support for [date & time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: You can use date() for time as well.
See this link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Wow guys, take it easy on the newbie!

Comment: @Spider at least someone understands that everyone was once a beginner just because i'm a girl doesnt mean i cannot code or learn how to

Comment: @Nicole, the guys here are really sticky with questions needing to be very specific, clear and well explained, and it also helps to show that you may have tried to look up something. For example, mentioning that you found a date() function but not a time() function will have shown effort from your side. This being said, they are still being really harsh with you. You can by the way, edit your question, and some of the downvoters may come back and upvote. You can also delete your question to get your 6 points back, but I think your question is valid and they're being a bit mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use date() instead, which is something I've just done on my website:

```
<?php echo date("D M d, Y G:i a"); ?>
```

it's explained in a little more detail here, as regards formatting. Maybe you want:

```
<?php echo date("G:i"); ?>
```

the formatting is up to you, but date() is what you want ;-)

Comment: sorry I could not comment on this question but I don't have enough reputation:-)

Comment: i want it to show like 22:05:03

Comment: Then you would have G:i:s or H:i:s. You need to read http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and see what G, g, H, i etc etc all mean, it is very simple.