# Need to convert a string(time) in sql to real date in php

Tags: php, sql, date, time

I have a table with a time (int 4) where is stored time ex:1506201203

That would be:

```
year-mo-da-hh-mm
2015-06-20-12-03
```

I need a php script to get the time and display it correctly ..

A bit of help ?

Comment: already has an answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [from_unixtime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

`FROM_UNIXTIME(column_name, '%Y-%m-%d')` in your MySQL query.

Or you can just use `date` function.

```
date('Y-m-d-h-m', $n['date']).
```

Comment: Except that it isn't a unix timestamp