# PHP convert string into a date

Tags: php, string, date, format, character

Hi I am new into PHP and I really really like it so var. I have a string which I want to convert into a custom date and time by adding just simple characters. I first tried fixing it by myself, but everything I tried didn't worked for me.

**Input:**

`$customdate = "27032017042100";`

I want to add to the string above characters like: **/** and **:**

**Expected result:**

`27/03/2017 04:21:00`

Comment: Why don't you simply take a look into the php documentation to learn about the date functions? http://php.net/manual/en/refs.calendar.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changing date format from one to another.**

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/761774)

```
$date = date_create_from_format('dmYHis', '27032017042100');
echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple date function:

```
echo date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
```

See http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple.

```
<?php
    $customdate = "27032017042100";
    echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $customdate);
?>
```

Here is the previous answered question: [Converting a UNIX Timestamp to Formatted Date String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert your data from STRING, you can use folowing code

```
if (preg_match("/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/", $customdate, $rg))
    $newdate = $rg[1]."/".$rg[2]."/".$rg[3]." ".$rg[4].":".$rg[5].":".$rg[6]
```