# convert submit_field time contact 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have contact 7 db wordpress  (4.9.2) plugin and in the database it stores `submit_field` in table `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` like

```
1516444550.8338 and converts to
2018-01-20 10:35:50 +00:00
```

so how does it convert this to a time and date as I need to read this field? This isn't seconds past 1970 it seems.

Comment: Duplicated question, see answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string

Comment: didnt get the exact answer from the post you talk about but this is $timestamp=1516448523.5316;  gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)