# Wordpress PHP shortcode returning Unix date stamp. How to convert to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a page builder on my Wordpress site which allows editing of the PHP. 
On a page I wanted to add a custom field which shows an expiry date set by a plugin.

I did this by adding:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[oxygen data='meta' key='_expiration-date']"); ?>
```

This works, but the date and time returned is in a Unix format(?) so it looks like: 
**1538329800**

Is there a way to convert this number to a proper text output to be displayed on pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a UNIX Timestamp to Formatted Date String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
<?php echo date("d/m/Y",do_shortcode("[oxygen data='meta' key='_expiration-date']")); ?>
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use This (I included time as well if you want that too0

```
echo date("d-m-Y h:i:sa", do_shortcode("[oxygen data='meta' key='_expiration-date']"));
```