# Format timestamp with PHP

Tags: php, time

I need to format this -> 1584094135205

I have tried these two functions:

```
date ("Y-m-d", strtotime (1584094135205))
// 1969-12-31 21:00:00

date ("Y-m-d", 1584094135205);
// 52167-12-11
```

The value is saved in a database from a Minecraft server when they are registered.

The date that should be output is: **2020-01-12**

Comment: Try  `echo date("Y-m-d", ($ts / 1000) );` where `$ts` is the value from the db.

Comment: Today's timestamp is ~1586365919. Yours timestamp = 1584094135205, you have 3 "extra digits". How are you saving this timestamp?

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040291/converting-a-unix-timestamp-to-formatted-date-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timestamp is in milliseconds, while `date` expects it in seconds.

Divide it by 1000.

```
date("Y-m-d", 1584094135205/1000);
// 2020-03-13
```